# How can I remove the Damage Flash?

Tags: minetest

I would like to remove the Damage flash in Minetest.  There does not seem to be any setting in the game to remove it.

I am trying to remove the damage flash by removing that code from the files that are contained in the Minetest directory.  I was able to use this method to remove the blood particles.  The problem is that I am not a coder, and although I have a reasonably good gist of what the code is doing, I cannot find the code that creates the damage flash for every time you take damage.

Could someone help me find this code?  If not, do you know of another way to remove the damage flash from the game?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you can't since it's a harcoded feature, in any case you may somehow mitigate the effec:

*You can use minetest.register_on_player_hpchange, but if you try to remove fall damage completely, players will still experience the “red damage flash” because fall damage is calculated client-wise

*Nodes that deal direct damage do so always once per second (with damage_per_second); no other time interval is possible

*How breath works in general You lose breath or take drowning damage every 2 seconds, and you regain breath every 0.5 seconds

I know this is bad news, but if this is part of the core design of the game, I guess the only way is to convince the game developer to do it...

For more reference, take a look [here](https://dev.minetest.net/List_of_hardcoded_features)

Comment: Am I able to change the color of the effect to something like white or black?

Comment: According to [this thread][1] the red flash is already reduced to avoid the blindness of the player, in any case doesn't seem to be removed... sorry pal..


  [1]: https://github.com/minetest/minetest/pull/4573

Comment: welp thx for the help

Comment: Coming back to this once again... :(  Is it at all possible to mod it so that this can be removed?

Comment: I really need to be able to either remove the damage flash or change its color.  If that's possible by either making configuration files or modding it somehow, I would love to know!